# AWS cognito not sending verification sms to US phone number

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I am using AWS cognito with my user pool, but when I register new user with a US phone number it doesn't send verification sms to US phone number. My AWS region is Asia Pacific (Sydney) ap-southeast-2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to check your logs to see what they tell you... post some of the error messages here

Comment: I can't the error, but I found the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to send SMS messages to US phone numbers, you must set up an
> origination ID in Amazon Pinpoint. You may be redirected to the Amazon
> Pinpoint console in a different region. Learn more.

You should create new US phone number in Amazon Pinpoint and connect it to your SNS console, then the cognito can send SMS message to US phone numbers.